# why methodLists is a pointer to pointer in objc_class

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

both methodLists and protocols are chain-table,
protocols is a pointer, but methodLists is a pointer to pointer, Why?

[image: ocjc_class]
[image: objc_method_list]
[image: objc_protocol_list]

Answer (score 3):

This is an implementation detail that is fallout from how both the history of Objective-C and the ability to dynamically add methods to classes.

Specifically, if you look at the contents of the method_list entries, you'll find that the methods are broken up into sets where each set contains all the methods from a particular category on the object.   I.e. if your app were to define a category on UIView with five methods (don't do that -- bad design), then you'd find those five methods tacked on to the end of the method_list in a single objc_method_list (which is why the method_list entry is pointer aligned and variable sized).

This also extends to dynamic addition of methods.   There is no need to bcopy a bunch of data into a newly allocated copy of the existing method data structure.   Instead, the runtime can just allocate an objc_method_list and shove it on the end of the linked list (or at the head -- implementation detail).